# MySQL ORDER CLAUSE ERROR

Tags: mysql, join, union

I am getting an error that says:
 "Unknown column 'story2.time' in 'order clause'"

My SQL statement is:

```
mysql_query("SELECT headline, story2.time FROM story2 WHERE username='Michael' UNION
SELECT headline, story2.time FROM story2 JOIN subscriptions WHERE subscriptions.subpaperid = story2.artnewsid AND subscriptions.papernameurl =  story2.papernameurl AND subscriptions.username = 'Michael' UNION 
SELECT headline, story2.time FROM story2 JOIN bookmark WHERE bookmark.writername = story2.username AND bookmark.articleid = story2.random AND bookmark.username = 'Michael'
ORDER BY story2.time DESC LIMIT 0,25") or die(mysql_error());
```

Any help on making the below query work would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can't reference `story2` in the order by with the `union` -- it no longer exists.  Just remove it -- `order by time desc...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `table` alias in the `order by`.  So, just do:

```
SELECT headline, story2.time
FROM story2
WHERE username='Michael'
UNION
SELECT headline, story2.time
FROM story2 JOIN
     subscriptions
WHERE subscriptions.subpaperid = story2.artnewsid AND subscriptions.papernameurl =  story2.papernameurl AND subscriptions.username = 'Michael'
UNION 
SELECT headline, story2.time
FROM story2 JOIN
     bookmark
WHERE bookmark.writername = story2.username AND bookmark.articleid = story2.random AND bookmark.username = 'Michael'
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 0, 25
```

The table name is only in scope for each subquery in the `union`.  By the way, you should use `union all` unless you intentionally want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Column name of union result is set to time, so just order by time.